# detect value from firebase and remove from superView if is true

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a cardView very similar to tinder. I am trying to detect if the user has swiped and if the user has, remove the card from the superView.

my firebase structure looks like,

[image: firstImage]

and how I am attempting to remove the card is,

```
func fetchUserSwipes() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("userSwipesForCU").child(uid!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
                self.user = user
                
                let poster = Poster(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
                let cardView = self.setupCardFromUser(poster: poster)
                
    
                if snapshot.exists(){
                    cardView.removeFromSuperview()
                    print("this value exist and should not present to card view")
                      }else{
                          print("this value does not exist")
                      }
   
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

If the user has swiped on the card previously, I would like for the card not to show. I don't receive errors when testing the code, but it does not execute. If the snapshot exists matching the current card, it should be removed.

after a little more investigating, I have managed to create the code below. This code somewhat works but not in the way I am hoping. It still saves the code and when I refresh the page the cards that were saved to firebase don't show however it just shows dummy cards.

```
 func fetchUserSwipes() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "userSwipesForCU")
    ref.child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
            self.user = user
            
            let poster = Poster(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
            let cardView = self.setupCardFromUser(poster: poster)

            if cardView == ref.child("fromId"){
                cardView.removeFromSuperview()
                print("this value exist and should not present to card view")
                  }else{
                print("this value does not exist")
                    
                  }

        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: "it does not execute" Can you clarify what you mean by that? For example, if you put a breakpoint on `if let userDictionary = ...` and run the code in a debugger, does it reach that line? If not, what happens if you also attach a `cancel` handler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observesingleeventof:with:withcancel: Does *that* get called?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your suggestion! adding the withCancel did help and now the function is called. I can see this represented in the console. Now my main issue, the cards still show up. Would I have to check and see if the id of the card is equal to the id saved in firebase then remove the cards?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did what i said above, and it worked a little but not exactly how I wanted. I updated my code to show what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the get data once method
Official Firebase Docs here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once

```
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Database.database().reference().child("userSwipesForCU").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

              if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
            self.user = user
            
            let poster = Poster(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
            let cardView = self.setupCardFromUser(poster: poster)
            

            if snapshot.exists(){
                cardView.removeFromSuperview()
                print("this value exist and should not present to card view")
                  }else{
                      print("this value does not exist")
                  }
```

Comment: This did help a little but I am still facing an issue. It keeps the cards there, but it makes them blank instead of removing them fully.

Comment: Hi there, please add some example code to illustrate, and paste in the relevant documentation to hedge against link-rot.